# How to initialize ComObject for Microsoft Access in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-access-2016

I am trying to programmatically access my Microsoft Access 2016 database (.accdb, but I can use .accde as well) using PowerShell (for automation, command-line use, etc). However, when I check the value of the object after initialization, I receive an error.

Following is the code I'm having trouble with.

```
$accessApp = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
```

After initialization,

```
$accessApp
```

The result is:

```
format-default : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

However, I can enter:

```
$accessApp.GetType()
```

To get:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     False    ApplicationClass                         System.__ComObject
```

When I enter:

```
$accessApp.CurrentProject | Select *
```

I get:

```
AllForms                   : 
AllReports                 : 
AllMacros                  : 
AllModules                 : 
AllDataAccessPages         : 
ProjectType                : 
BaseConnectionString       : 
IsConnected                : True
Name                       : 
Path                       : 
FullName                   : 
Connection                 : 
Properties                 : 
Application                : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass
Parent                     : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.ApplicationClass
RemovePersonalInformation  : False
FileFormat                 : 
AccessConnection           : 
ImportExportSpecifications : 
IsTrusted                  : 
WebSite                    : 
IsWeb                      : 
Resources                  : 
IsSQLBackend               :
```

Most of the values are null. I'd like to be able to get things like All Reports from this variable, but I cannot.

To me it seems like there is an issue when initializing the ComObject. Is this expected behavior and something I just need to work around, or does there appear to be something wrong?

Let me know if more information is needed. This is my first post.

**UPDATE**
`$accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($DatabasePath)` must be added to connect to the database before accessing all reports. `$accessApp` still displays an error, but not when used with `Select`, so perhaps there is just not a default view.

Comment: Your experience suggests that the first error _may_ only be a problem with default _display output_, which may also affect the display output of `$accessApp.CurrentProject | Select *` Do you get the intended information if you try `$accessApp.CurrentProject.AllReports | Select *`, for instance?

Comment: Unfortunately,  ```$accessApp.CurrentProject.AllReports``` is null, so ```$accessApp.CurrentProject.AllReports | Select * ``` returns nothing. I was hoping this was perhaps just due to an issue with initialization. As shown in the OP, almost all of the properties are null in ```$accessApp.CurrentProject```.

Comment: I see. Just to rule out an obvious problem: you have made sure that you've opened a database file first? (Perhaps if you didn't, `$accessApp.CurrentProject` would be `$null` - I don't know, because I don't have access to MS Access (no pun intended).)

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing. In my various iterations, I had used ```$accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($DatabasePath)```, but I guess I had the order mixed up. When I add this line first, I now have data. Thank you for helping me with the obvious.

Comment: Glad to hear the main mystery is solved, though the one about `$accessApp` by itself causing an error during to-display output remains (which may not be a problem in practice, however).